# How can I make the text of this div wrap?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML structure that looks like:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="caption">
        <div class="title">This is a very, very long title!!!</div>
        <div class="details">Details</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

I've styled this very simply:

```css
.container {
    min-width: 200px;
}
.caption {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.title {
    float: left;
}
.details {
    float: right;
}
.content {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
```

Which looks like:

[image: css-example]

If I shrink the window enough eventually the "details" div will wrap to the next line:

[image: css-example2]

What I would like to happen is the text inside the "title" div wrap to the next line but keep both "title" and "details" at the same line (not wrapping).

Something like:

```
This is a very, very         Details
long title!!!
+----------------------------------+
```

With the title only wrapping once there isn't enough space as the window is resized.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for achieving this?

[Here is a jsFiddle of the above code if anyone is interested.](http://jsfiddle.net/3nBDd/1/)

Edit: To clarify, I'd like to not specify a fixed width for .title if possible.  In most cases I'd like to let this div get as wide as it needs.

Comment: `.title { max-width: 200px; /* or whatever */ }`?

Comment: Is it possible to do this without specifying a max-width / width?  I'd prefer to let the width get as wide as needed.  In most cases the window and title will be quite large.  Maybe a min-width would do the trick?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what browser are you using?

Comment: Mobile Chrome and Mobile Safari

Answer (score 2):

this should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/KV8UW/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="caption">
    <div class="details">Details</div>
    <div class="title">This is a very, very long title!!!</div>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

```
.container {
    min-width: 200px;
}
.caption {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.details {
    float: right;
}
.content {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use display for your layout:http://jsfiddle.net/3nBDd/15/

```
.caption {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.title {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align: left;
}
.details {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upate your div Title as below and it will wrap the text.

```
.title
{
    float: left;
    width: 100px; //or whatever you want
}
```

or

```
.title
{
    float: left;
    width: 20%; //or whatever you want
}
```

Comment: I'd like to not specify a fixed width for this div if possible.  This window can expanded to be pretty wide and this would cut off labels at an arbitrary length.

Comment: use percentage, eg. `.title { width: 40%; }`  `.details { width: 58%; }`